# Hodu "lacking spelling"

Tags: spelling-variants

Is there any significance given as to why this particular word "הדו" out of all the other "הודו" in psalms is the only one that is written in "חסר" form; i.e. not in its full spelling?

> הדו לה' כי טוב׃

[Psalms 107:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.107.1)

Comment: I've always seen it spelled מלא.

Comment: @N.T. https://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/x/x26a7.htm.             where have you seen it מלא ?

Comment: My Mikraos Gedolos and every siddur I remember. Probably a typo on their end. No comment on it in Minchas Shai, either.

Comment: @N.T. The Mesorah on that posuk (https://www.mgketer.org/mikra/27/107/1/mg/72) has 'ל' חס, standing for לית חסר - there is no other example in Tanach (besides this one) of this word written chaser.